# SurefireReflectionException

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, tycho-surefire-plugin

When running maven install, i get to following cryptic error message

```
org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.OsgiSurefireBooter.run(OsgiSurefireBooter.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.HeadlessTestApplication.run(HeadlessTestApplication.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4TestChecker.isValidJUnit4Test(JUnit4TestChecker.java:63)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4TestChecker.accept(JUnit4TestChecker.java:52)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultDirectoryScanner.locateTestClasses(DefaultDirectoryScanner.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.scanClassPath(JUnit4Provider.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:83)
    ... 28 more
```

My effective Pom looks like this (quite large :-():

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>group</groupId>
  <artifactId>project</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>eclipse-test-plugin</packaging>
  <properties>
    <xtext.version>2.8.4</xtext.version>
    <tycho-version>0.20.0</tycho-version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.xtend</groupId>
          <artifactId>xtend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.4</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>xtend-install-debug-info</goal>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
                <goal>xtend-test-install-debug-info</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>xtend-gen</outputDirectory>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>xtend-gen</outputDirectory>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.20.0</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>0.20.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <environments>
            <environment>
              <os>linux</os>
              <ws>gtk</ws>
              <arch>x86</arch>
            </environment>
            <environment>
              <os>linux</os>
              <ws>gtk</ws>
              <arch>x86_64</arch>
            </environment>
            <environment>
              <os>win32</os>
              <ws>win32</ws>
              <arch>x86</arch>
            </environment>
            <environment>
              <os>macosx</os>
              <ws>cocoa</ws>
              <arch>x86_64</arch>
            </environment>
          </environments>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.20.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <skipTests>false</skipTests>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <skipTests>false</skipTests>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.20.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-package-plugin</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>package-plugin</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-build-qualifier</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>build-qualifier</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-validate-id</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>validate-id</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-validate-version</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>validate-version</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-p2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.20.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-p2-metadata-default</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>p2-metadata-default</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-update-local-index</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>update-local-index</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.20.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

What might be worth noting is, that the tests i am trying to run are Junit Plugin Tests, if there is anything i can post to help let me know :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that JUnit JAR is a dependency of at least test scope.  From the stack trace, it looks like the problem is coming from Tycho running surefire.  The NPE is occurring because [runWith](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.maven.surefire/common-junit4/2.8.1/org/apache/maven/surefire/common/junit4/JUnit4TestChecker.java#46) in JUnit4TestChecker is null, which is loaded from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.maven.surefire/common-junit4/2.8.1/org/apache/maven/surefire/common/junit4/JUnit4TestChecker.java#98).

I have no knowledge about Tycho, but it might also be possible to add JUnit dependency to the tycho plugin itself instead of the project.

Comment: Hey, i don't really understand it 100% but i will toy around with adding JUnit as dependency. Thanks for giving me a starting point. I will check back here after i tested it :-)

Comment: Turns out this was the problem: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-825  The Manifest.MF was only importing org.junit and not org.junit.runner aswell :-)